# Different Law of Cosines using Sine instead: $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, triangles

Playing around with Trig and the Law of Cosines (LoC), I came up with this formula given a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ where we are given $a$, $b$ and angle $\theta$ between them:

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$$

Far from me the idea that I could've stumbled onto something no one's ever derived before, but I've never seen this formula and was just curious whether it has a name or is never considered because it offers no advantage over the LoC (needing the same amount of initial information) and is slightly more complicated.

Also, is my proof correct?

[image]

Here's my work; here I use $C$ for the angle:

$$c^2 = x^2 + h^2$$

$$h = a \sin(C)$$

$$h^2 = a^2 \sin^2(C)$$

$$x = b - (b-x)$$

$$(b-x) = \sqrt{a^2 - h^2} = \sqrt{a^2 - a^2 \sin^2(C)} = \sqrt{a^2 (1-\sin^2(C))}$$

$$x = b-a\sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)}$$

$$x^2 = b^2 - 2ab \sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)} + a^2 (1-\sin^2(C))$$

Therefore:

$$c^2 = b^2 - 2ab \sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)} + a^2 (1-\sin^2(C)) + a^2 \sin^2(C)$$

$$c^2 = b^2 - 2ab \sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)} + a^2 (1-\sin^2(C) + \sin^2(C))$$

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)}$$

Comment: What you stumbled on is completely trivial since $\;\cos^2x=1-\sin^2 x\;$ ....sorry.

Comment: @Timbuc, no worries, as I said I didn't think for one second I had stumbled upon something never discovered before, I was just wondering what it was exactly and now I know :)

Comment: you can just use Pythagoras's identity for the proof and finish it up quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the nature of the square root I think this equation you have is less useful than the 'usual' Law of Cosines. We have that $$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta_c)$$ where $\theta_c$ is the angle opposite of the triangle side $c$. By the Pythagorean Theorem we also know $$\sin^2(\theta_c)+\cos^2(\theta_c) = 1$$ and solving for $\cos(\theta_c)$ gets us $\cos(\theta_c) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)}$, hence in a single step we can get to the equation you have, $$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)}$$ However we also know that $\cos(\theta_c)$ will be negative when $\pi/2 < \theta_c <3\pi/2$, while $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)}$ will always be non-negative. So you would need to make cases for your equation to be accurate. $$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)} \quad \text{when} \space -\pi/2 \leq \theta_c \leq \pi/2$$ and $$c^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)} \quad \text{when} \space \pi/2 < \theta_c <3\pi/2$$ At this point it seems more reasonable to avoid cases and use the 'usual' Law of Cosines.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean about the cases. If $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta_c)}$ is always non-negative, why do we need different cases?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yours is same as the cosine rule. Recall that
$$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$$
Now note that if $C$ is acute, we then have that $\cos(C) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)}$. Hence, we obtain
$$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2(C)}$$
Your proof is fine, though note that if $\angle{C}$ were to be obtuse, then writing $x$ as $b+(x-b)$ would be the right way to go about.

Comment: Thank you, good point about the obtuse angle.

Answer (score 1):

Really this just boils down to the identity $$\cos^2{x} = 1 - \sin^2{x}$$
So no, your formula is really no different from the Law of cosines. Your proof looks fine however.

Having believed I found a new trigonometric law once (*and being incorrect*), my advice would be to always exhaust your result for any known identities to see if you simply have another representation of a known law or expression. Resources like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can help for easier cases.

Comment: Thank you; I agree, it's just that my knowledge of Trig identities is basically non-existent and I'm just going through Trig very visually/geometrically trying to rederive stuff, which I feel helps me understand the material best.
But I'm definitely going to get to those soon :) and in the meantime I'll check Wolfram for sure, good point.